# Erlang: gen_server crashes when started over supervisor

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

So, i spent LOTS of time and still didn't find the answer.

I have simple tcp server in gen_server, which accepts messages via telnet and print them in console:

```
-module(st_server).

-behaviour(gen_server).
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Include files
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------

%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% External exports
-export([start_link/0, start_link/1, stop/0]).

%% gen_server callbacks
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2, code_change/3]).

-define(SERVER, ?MODULE).
-define(DEFAULT_PORT, 1055).

-record(state, {lsock, port}).

%% ====================================================================
%% External functions
%% ====================================================================

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @doc Starts the server.
%%
%% @spec start_link(Port::integer()) -> {ok, Pid}
%% where
%%  Pid = pid()
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
start_link(Port) ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, [Port], []),
    io:format("Server name: ~w, port: ~w.~n", [?SERVER, Port]).

%% @spec start_link() -> {ok, Pid}
%% @doc Calls `start_link(Port)' using the default port.
start_link() -> start_link(?DEFAULT_PORT).

%%-------------------------------------------------------------------- 
%% @doc Stops the server. 
%% @spec stop() -> ok 
%% @end 
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------- 
stop() ->
    gen_server:cast(?SERVER, stop).

%% ====================================================================
%% Server functions
%% ====================================================================

%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Function: init/1
%% Description: Initiates the server
%% Returns: {ok, State}          |
%%          {ok, State, Timeout} |
%%          ignore               |
%%          {stop, Reason}
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
init([Port]) ->
    {ok, LSock} = gen_tcp:listen(Port, [{active, true}]),
    {ok, #state{lsock = LSock, port = Port}, 0}.

%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Function: handle_cast/2
%% Description: Handling cast messages
%% Returns: {noreply, State}          |
%%          {noreply, State, Timeout} |
%%          {stop, Reason, State}            (terminate/2 is called)
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
handle_cast(stop, State) ->
    {stop, normal, State}.

handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
    {reply, ok, State}.

%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Function: handle_info/2
%% Description: Handling all non call/cast messages
%% Returns: {noreply, State}          |
%%          {noreply, State, Timeout} |
%%          {stop, Reason, State}            (terminate/2 is called)
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------


handle_info({tcp, _Socket, Data}, State) ->
    io:format("Incoming info: ~s", [Data]),
    {noreply, State};

handle_info({tcp_closed, _Socket}, #state{lsock = LSock} = State) ->
    {ok, _Sock} = gen_tcp:accept(LSock),
    {noreply, State};

handle_info(timeout, #state{lsock = LSock} = State) ->
    {ok, _Sock} = gen_tcp:accept(LSock),
    {noreply, State}.

%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Function: terminate/2
%% Description: Shutdown the server
%% Returns: any (ignored by gen_server)
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
terminate(Reason, _State) ->
    io:format("~nServer shutdown. Reason: ~s.~n", [Reason]),
    ok.

%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Func: code_change/3
%% Purpose: Convert process state when code is changed
%% Returns: {ok, NewState}
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
code_change(_OldVsn, _State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, _State}.

%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%%% Internal functions
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And supervisor:

```
-module(st_sup).

-behaviour(supervisor).
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Include files
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------

%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% External exports
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
-export([]).

%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Internal exports
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
-export([
     init/1,
     start_link/0
        ]).

%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Macros
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
-define(SERVER, ?MODULE).

%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Records
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------

%% ====================================================================
%% External functions
%% ====================================================================

start_link() ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, []).

%% ====================================================================
%% Server functions
%% ====================================================================
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Func: init/1
%% Returns: {ok,  {SupFlags,  [ChildSpec]}} |
%%          ignore                          |
%%          {error, Reason}
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
init([]) ->
    Server = {st_server, {st_server, start_link, []},
                permanent, 2000, worker, [st_server]},
    Children = [Server],
    RestartStrategy = {one_for_one, 0, 1},
    {ok, {RestartStrategy, Children}}.

%% ====================================================================
%% Internal functions
%% ====================================================================
```

I start this in erlang console:

```
st_sup:start_link().
```

And get this:

```
Server name: st_server, port: 1055.
** exception exit: shutdown
```

This means, that supervisor shuts down server for some reason.
If I start server by itself (st_server:start_link.) it works just fine.

So, the question is how to make this work without shutdowns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a glance, it's probably because the return value of `st_server:start_link/1` is the return value of the call to `io:format/2`.

This is fine when you call `st_server:start_link()` directly in the REPL, but the supervisor is probably expecting a return value more like `{ok, Pid}`.

You can fix this just by swapping the two lines in `st_server:start_link/1`, so that it returns the value of the call to `gen_server:start_link/4`:

```
start_link(Port) ->    
    io:format("Server name: ~w, port: ~w.~n", [?SERVER, Port]),
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, [Port], []).
```

Comment: but that's kind of strange for ordinal languages like c, java. That means, that supervisors tracks all output channels.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "tracks all output channels". But the return value of a function is always the last expression, including when it is `io:format`, which has a return value `ok`.

Comment: The output is irrelevant, it is the *return value* which is important. Erlang is a functional language and every operation always returns a value.

Answer (score 1):

A strange value is also the supervisor's `RestartStrategy` which is set to `{one_for_one,0,1}`. This means that the supervisor will give up up after more than zero restarts in 1 second, in effect it will give up after the first crash by a child. Which is not usually not what you want a supervisor to do.

Comment: (I may be wrong, but it looks like he adapted an example from the book "Erlang and OTP in Action", which has that exact `RestartStrategy` and also explains that this is not a normal configuration.)